# Nested categories with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have **mongoid** model with some entries and want to organize them into categories. Categories should have an option to ne nested like this:

```
Videos:
-Car video
-Gadgets Video
--iPad
--Android
Music:
-Pop
--Madonna
-Rap
--2pac
--50cent
```

How can I do it with **mongoid**? The order of categories does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized a nested category model with '[mongoid_tree](https://github.com/ticktricktrack/mongoid_tree)'. It's pretty straight forward.

```
root = Category.new { :name => "Root Category" }
child = Category.new { :name => "Child Category" }
childs_child = Category.new { :name => "Child Child Category" }

root.children << child
root.save
child.children << childs_child
child.save

# get all root categories
Category.where("parent_ids" => []).first
 => "#<Category _id: 4d63cbdf2507e40d03000018, child_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('4d63cbdf2507e40d03000019')], parent_ids: [], name: \"Root Category\">"
```

Julian

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mongoid Nested Set](https://github.com/blt04/mongoid_nested_set):

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  acts_as_nested_set
end
```

---

**UPDATED**

There are different patterns of [Trees in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB). `Acts_as_nested_set` is the DRTW (don't reinvent the wheel) solution but others may fit you better.

Comment: This gem supports node position features like `move_to_left_of(other_node), `move_to_right_of(other_node)`, `move_to_child_of(other_node)`... I is'nе necessary amd I want to find a KISS-way solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch what the problem actually is with this methods. Even the simplest `acts_as_tree` provide you with `move_xx` methods. You can use it or not, it's fully up to you. What about Rails? It has a lot of methods which you don't use. Is Rails not a "KISS-way" to make webapps? :) Only best gems ported for Mongoid now-days. And AwesomeNestedSet is one of them.  BTW if you find another solution, please post it here :)

Answer (score 1):

For mongoid nested set, the correct link is : https://github.com/thinkwell/mongoid_nested_set.

Really nice lib. acts_as_nested uses less query.